# Derivatives of ODE trajectories w.r.t function values at specific time points - definitions in the neural ODEs paper

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, neural-networks

I'm trying to understand proofs in the [Neural ODE paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.07366.pdf) Appendix A, B.

And i'm stuck at the definitions. Equation (34) is introduced as "We will prove that if we define an adjoint state $a(t)=\frac{dL}{dz(t)}$ then ..."

Where $L$ is defined in equation (3): $L(\ z(t_1))=L(z(t_0)+\int_{t_0}^{t_1}f(z(t),t,\theta)dt\ )$ with scalar function $L$. And $z(t)$ satisfies $z'(t)=f(z(t),t,\theta)$.

Similarly the authors use $\frac{dT_{\epsilon} (z(t))}{dz(t)}$ where $T_\epsilon (z(t))=z(t+\epsilon)=z(t)+\int_{t}^{t+\epsilon}f(z(s),s,\theta)ds$ in (15)-(27).

But what are these derivatives $\frac{dT_{\epsilon} (z(t))}{dz(t)},\ \frac{dL}{dz(t)}$? How are they defined? They doesn't seem to be standard derivatives or Frechet derivatives of operators...

**Upd**:

Ok, it seems that $\frac{dL}{dz(t)}$ can be interpreted as just $L'(z(t))$, though i am still not sure. And i  still don't understand what is $\frac{dz(t+\epsilon)}{dz(t)}$ and how to get this from the chain rule (Appendix B, eq. 38):
$$\frac{dL}{\partial z(t)}=\frac{dL}{d z(t+\epsilon)}\frac{dz(t+\epsilon)}{dz(t)}$$

**Upd 1**:

From [Neural ODE definition of derivative $\frac{d L}{dz(t)}$ (adjoint)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4003376/neural-ode-definition-of-derivative-fracd-ldzt-adjoint) it seems that
$$\frac{dL}{dz(t)} \neq L'(z(t))$$

Answer (score 1):

It is easier than you might think. It all comes from Pontryagin maximum principle and the theory of Lagrange multipliers. You can check a follow up work of the original neural ODEs for the formal derivation of the Adjoint equations [1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.08063.pdf).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Yes, thanks. However, i know how to derive adjoint sensitivity method using Lagrange multipliers, but i want to understand proofs in the neural ODEs paper where they present an alternative way.